# How to generate all the combinations from a matrix and assign each possible outcome a unique value?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a matrix

```
mat1<-matrix(c('b','c','q','a','z','d','t','o','p'),nrow=3,ncol=3)
```

How do I generate a list of all the possible combinations from left to right, right to left, top to bottom and bottom to top? Say, 'bc','bcq','qcb' and so on. Also, I will assign each of the element a unique element based on the position of the words. For example, 'bc' corresponds to '1112' while 'bcq' corresponds to '1113', 'qcb' corresponds to '1311'.

Comment: Why not the diagonals. `"bc"` is not a combination of a row or column, it is a subset/substring of one. If you want *combinations*, why does left-to-right differ from right-to-left? That is perfectly redundant, unless you mean "permutations", but still since you say right-to-left, that suggests that with a row of `"b","a","t"`, you can derive `"b"`, `"a"`, `"t"`, `"ba"`, `"bt"`, `"at"`, `"bat"` (from left-to-right), then add `"t"`, `"ta"`, `"tb"`, `"ab"`, `"tab"`. Once you have a list of all of these, how do you intend to then add values of 1112, 1113, 1311, ... to each of them?

Comment: sorry for my choice of vocabulary.... i think substring migjht be more appropriate and i mean permutation

Comment: Are all of those substring permutations exactly what you expect from the top row of the matrix? It helps, especially with problems as confusing as this one, to have at least a portion of your expected output. Also, what code have you tried so far to implement this? It is generally preferred to start with whatever you've already tried.

Comment: @r2evans I only tried the basic combn command so far and have no clue what to do next... I don't quite understand what do you mean by "what you expect from the top row of the matrix".

Comment: It's is a homework practice, the teacher will provide a vector of vocabularies and a n*n matrix, with each entry a single characters. We are asked to write a programme such that if any of the vocabulary appears in the matrix, we need to return a list of vectors containing their positions with length 4, (r of first letter, c of first letter, r of last letter, c of last letter). @r2evans

Comment: We do not need to consider diagonal cases which is why I exclude this possibility from my consideration. I think all these possible permuations can assign to a unque length-4 vector but I have no idea how to do it yet

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
perms <- function(vec) {
  f <- function(v0) unlist(sapply(seq_along(v0)[-1], function(i) {
    apply(combn(v0, i), 2, paste0, collapse="")
  }))
  c(vec, f(vec), f(rev(vec)))
}

unique(c(sapply(1:2, function(i) apply(m, i, perms))))
#  [1] "b"   "a"   "t"   "ba"  "bt"  "at"  "bat" "ta"  "tb"  "ab"  "tab" "c"  
# [13] "z"   "o"   "cz"  "co"  "zo"  "czo" "oz"  "oc"  "zc"  "ozc" "q"   "d"  
# [25] "p"   "qd"  "qp"  "dp"  "qdp" "pd"  "pq"  "dq"  "pdq" "bc"  "bq"  "cq" 
# [37] "bcq" "qc"  "qb"  "cb"  "qcb" "az"  "ad"  "zd"  "azd" "dz"  "da"  "za" 
# [49] "dza" "to"  "tp"  "op"  "top" "po"  "pt"  "ot"  "pot"
```

This is how it works.

`apply` takes a matrix (`m`), an axis (`1` is "rows", `2` is "columns), and a function (`perms`):

```
apply(m, 1, perms)
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
#  [1,] "b"   "c"   "q"  
#  [2,] "a"   "z"   "d"  
#  [3,] "t"   "o"   "p"  
#  [4,] "ba"  "cz"  "qd" 
#  [5,] "bt"  "co"  "qp" 
#  [6,] "at"  "zo"  "dp" 
#  [7,] "bat" "czo" "qdp"
#  [8,] "ta"  "oz"  "pd" 
#  [9,] "tb"  "oc"  "pq" 
# [10,] "ab"  "zc"  "dq" 
# [11,] "tab" "ozc" "pdq"
```

It transposes the output (it's an R thing, sigh), so each row (from the `1`) is returned as a column. We want to run this function across both rows and columns, so they we also do

```
apply(m, 2, perms)
```

I was (in hindsight, "unfortunately") tricky by using `sapply` to iterate over the axes given to `apply`. The following two are similar-enough (in content if not precise structure):

```
c(apply(m,1,perms), apply(m,2,perms))
sapply(1:2, function(i) apply(m, 1, perms))
```

Perhaps that is just obfuscating things ...

The last part is `unique(...)`, which just takes out the duplicates.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I don't quite understand `function(v0) unlist(sapply(seq_along(v0)[-1], function(i) { apply(combn(v0, i), 2, paste0, collapse="")` this part of the code. Could you please explain to me what this code is doing?